# How I could get the last value per record in awk?

Tags: awk

Im triying to get the last value per record but I dont know how

This is my input

```
grey;5
grey;6
grey;3
blue:2
blue;1
blue;0
red;5
red;7
red;2
```

I need to get this

```
grey;3
blue;0
red;2
```

Please help me with this

Comment: Please show what you have tried and why it didn't worked. Question like "I need X but don't know how" are not welcome on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
awk -F'[:;]' 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in A){print A[$1];delete A[$1]}'   Input_file  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

I just replaced the `:` with a `;`:

```
$ awk -F\; '{a[$1]=$0} END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' file
red;2
grey;3
blue;0
```

Explained: Hash everything based on the `$1`. In this case *last come, last served* or smth.